# Keyframe being ignored?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, keyframes

I'm probably missing something obvious, but it seems whenever I try to move the root bone of my character after frame 35, and add a keyframe, it's being ignored. I'll scrub along the timeline to the new keyframe, but the character doesn't move to the new position that I set.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an *Action* strip in the *NLA Editor* which is overriding/controlling the animation of the object.

Here I have added a keyframe on frame 54, but because the end of the *Action Strip* is at 35 (green timeline marker), the keyframe is ignored:

[image]

To solve this you can extend the *End Frame* property of the *Action Strip* in the *Properties* shelf on the right of the *NLA Editor* (<kbd>N</kbd>) to be as long as your animation:

[image]

Or, if you don't need to use the *NLA Editor*, you can delete the strip by selecting the *Action Strip* called 'Jump' (it will be yellow/orange when selected, as shown above), press <kbd>Space</kbd>, type "Delete Tracks" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Surely all that will do is extend/draw my current animation out and slow it down...? I would have thought the amount of the Action Strip's frames would keep increasing as I add more keyframes...? I don't recall setting it to 35 at the start...

Comment: I've just increased the end frame to 60, but any frames I add after 35 don't register either.

Comment: It doesn't slow the animation down it sets the range of where to look for keyframes within the original action. The exact steps I take with your file is to change to NLA, select 'Jump' strip, extend range, add new keyframe and it works.

Comment: Note that the panel in the screenshot is 'Active Clip' not 'Active Strip'. There are two panels that look quite similar and both have frame range options.

Comment: Ahaa... That's why I couldn't get it to work; I was adjusting the Active Strip. That worked. Thanks. :)